# How to see Azure table data in SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

As the title suggest, I want to merge my Azure table data with the data residing in Azure SQL. However, I dont want to replicate Azure SQL data to Azure table.

Anyway to have the Azure table in SSMS and then I could create a view over Azure table and Azure SQl together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Table Storage is not a relational database and does not support join query. To join existing data in Azure SQL Database with data on Azure Table Storage, you will have to replicate/import your data in Azure Table Storage into Azure SQL, and then use SSMS to perform the join. That's the only solution.

Elastic Database queries on Azure SQL Database allows cross database queries involving Azure Database tables or Azure SQL Data Warehouse tables only.

Comment: Actually, 80% of my organization's data is residing in Azure SQL and rest is in Azure table storage. I just want to analyze the both together. The best way I think is to create a external table in Azure SQL to the data pointing to Azure table storage. What do you reckon?

Comment: And I am choosing Azure table because I have been getting 1GB of Json data daily since 2015 which Azure SQL wont be able to handle and cosmos db is expensive. I dont think I can use appendblob because it has 195GB upper limit

Comment: Adding that data on Azure table storage to Azure SQL Data Warehouse could also makes sense. You can create an elastic query between tables on Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Comment: But I believe elastic query only works between Azure databases or with Datawarehouse. How does azure table comes into picture?

Comment: Are you willing to stop using Azure Table Storage in favor of Azure SQL Data Warehouse? This way you will satisfy the need to join the data currently stored in Azure Table Storage.

Comment: Good point but all of my data is in Azure SQL DB and migrating to Azure DWH, i am afraid, is not possible. But anyways, thanks Alberto I will marked this as the answer. What i am planning to do is, my raw data is already being pushed to Blob daily so I just use databricks to process it and then pushed the processed dataframe to Azure SQL DB.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your plans with me, Thank you for marking my reply as answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want for something like this is Elastic Query. You can [read more about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview). Pay attention to the warning about data movement though. This is good for querying, but it's not a great way to do large scale data moves.

Comment: But as alberto suggested, i guess it can only be used over different/remote Azure SQL DBs. Dont know how to use it over Azure table storage also.